# Array.filter() with async arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter my array using `Array.filter()` function, however I came across this issue.
I need to call some other function inside the `filter` function asynchronously. However the array is not changing its value based on the conditions that I define in the function.

```
const filterWithEmail = data.filter(async (doc) =>
{
   const findUser = await UserService.findUser(doc.id).catch(err => {});
   if (findUser)
   {
      const { email } = findUser;
      return regexFilter ? regexFilter.test(email.normalize("NFKC")) : false;
   }
});
```

This code doesn't affect the `data` array at all for some reason.
Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `.filter` expects synchronous predicate. Since you provide an async function, it just takes the returned promise as a truthy value and assumes everything passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` expects the return value of the callback to be a boolean but `async` functions always return a promise.

You don't know if you want to return `true` or `false` in time to tell `filter` which it is.

What you possibly want to do is:

1. `map` the data from `data` to `{ keep: true, original_data: data }` (using an `async` callback)
2. Pass the resulting array of promises to `Promise.all`
3. `await` the return value of `Promise.all`
4. `filter` that array with: `.filter(data => data.keep)`
5. Get the original objects back with `.map(data => data.original_data)`

Something along these lines (untested):

```
const filterWithEmail = (
  await Promise.all(
    data.map(async (data) => {
      const findUser = await UserService.findUser(doc.id).catch((err) => {});
      let keep = false;
      if (findUser && regexFilter)
        keep = regexFilter.test(email.normalize("NFKC"));
      return { data, keep };
    })
  )
)
  .filter((data) => data.keep)
  .map((data) => data.data);
```